# C# Measurement Conversion Class

Tags: c#, measurement, units-of-measurement

Alrighty, so I have been writing a class for kitchen measurements, for now it just has volume, or liquid, measurements, and I call it like this:

```
ktchnmsrmnts.VolumeMeasurements(number), current_measurement, to_measurement);
```

and from there it's perty simple for most people to figure out the inside code, just some simple math there. 
Now my issue is I need to add a option that says 'hey he gots 17.50 cups, lets make it 1 gallon, and 1 1/2 cups.

I was thinking of adding a new case to 'to_measurement' 
that checks to see if the number is greater then the highest measurement like say is 19 cups is greater than gallons, then it makes it 1 gallon and sends the remainders down the line, but I never use pints in the kitchen so maybe add another option of what to convert it too.. I don't know I'm stuck, and yes I know the code is basic but fits my needs, halfway anyways..

Just incase you need my full code, here ya go:

```
class KitchenMeasurements
{
    public double VolumeMeasurements(double number, string current_measurement, string to_measurement)
    {
        double mL = 0;
        double tsp= 0;
        double tbsp = 0;
        double fluid_ounces = 0;
        double cup = 0;
        double pint = 0;
        double quart = 0;
        double gallon = 0;
        double ounce = 0;
        double gram = 0;
        double pound = 0;
        double liter = 0;

        switch (current_measurement)
        {
            case "mL":
                mL = number;
                tsp = mL * 0.202884;
                tbsp = mL * 0.067628;
                fluid_ounces = mL * 0.033814;
                cup = mL * 0.00422675;
                pint = mL * 0.00211338;
                quart = mL * 0.00105669;
                gallon = mL * 0.000264172;
                liter = mL * 0.001;
                break;

            case "tsb":
                tsp = number;
                mL = tsp * 4.92892;
                tbsp = tsp * 0.333333;
                fluid_ounces = tsp * 0.166667;
                cup = tsp * 0.0208333;
                pint = tsp * 0.0104167;
                quart = tsp * 0.00520833;
                gallon = tsp * 0.00130208;
                liter = tsp * 0.00492892;
                break;

            case "tbsp":
                tbsp = number;
                mL = tbsp * 14.7868;
                tsp = tbsp * 3;
                fluid_ounces = tbsp * 0.5;
                cup = tbsp * 0.0625;
                pint = tbsp * 0.03125;
                quart = tbsp * 0.015625;
                gallon = tbsp * 0.00390625;
                liter = tbsp * 0.0147868;
                break;

            case "fluid ounce":
                fluid_ounces = number;
                mL = fluid_ounces * 29.5735;
                tsp = fluid_ounces * 6;
                tbsp = fluid_ounces * 2;
                cup = fluid_ounces * 0.125;
                pint = fluid_ounces * 0.0625;
                quart = fluid_ounces * 0.03125;
                gallon = fluid_ounces * 0.0078125;
                liter = fluid_ounces * 0.0295735;
                break;

            case "cup":
                cup = number;
                mL = cup * 236.588;
                tsp = cup * 48;
                tbsp = cup * 16;
                fluid_ounces = cup * 8;
                pint = cup * 0.5;
                quart = cup * 0.25;
                gallon = cup * 0.0625;
                liter = cup * 0.236588;
                break;

            case "pint":
                pint = number;
                mL = pint * 473.176;
                tsp = pint * 96;
                tbsp = pint * 32;
                fluid_ounces = pint * 16;
                cup = pint * 2;
                quart = pint * 0.5;
                gallon = pint * 0.125;
                liter = pint * 0.473176;
                break;

            case "quart":
                quart = number;
                mL = quart * 946.353;
                tsp = quart * 192;
                tbsp = quart * 64;
                fluid_ounces = quart * 32;
                cup = quart * 4;
                pint = quart * 2;
                gallon = quart * 0.25;
                liter = quart * 0.946353;
                break;

            case "gallon":
                gallon = number;
                mL = gallon * 3785.41;
                tsp = gallon * 768;
                tbsp = gallon * 256;
                fluid_ounces = gallon * 128;
                cup = gallon * 16;
                pint = gallon * 8;
                quart = gallon * 4;
                liter = gallon * 3.78541;
                break;

            case "liter":
                liter = number;
                mL = liter * 1000;
                tsp = liter * 202.884;
                tbsp = liter * 67.628;
                fluid_ounces = liter * 33.814;
                cup = liter * 4.22675;
                pint = liter * 2.11338;
                quart = liter * 1.05669;
                gallon = liter * 0.264172;
                break;
        }

        switch (to_measurement)
        {
            case "mL":
                return mL;
            case "tsb":
                return tsp;
            case "tbsp":
                return tbsp;
            case "fluid ounce":
                return fluid_ounces;
            case "cup":
                return cup;
            case "pint":
                return pint;
            case "quart":
                return quart;
            case "gallon":
                return gallon;
            case "ounce":
                return ounce;
            case "gram":
                return gram;
            case "pound":
                return pound;
            case "liter":
                return liter;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever up-voted this post please add the question to it so it can be answered. Side note: the sample code shows that basic inheritance leads to much more compact code as standard replacement for huge `switch` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what you were asking for, but I did see this:

> Now my issue is I need to add a option that says 'hey he gots 17.50 cups, lets make it 1 gallon, and 1 1/2 cups.

You would need to take a set of measurements and loop through them recalculating the remainders. I highly advise you to extract your method code into class variables and helper methods.

Below is some example code that should help you. You'll need to fill in the blanks.

```
public string ConvertToDescription(double amount, string originalMeasurement, params string[] toMeasurements)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    double valueToConvert = amount;
    string priorMeasurement = originalMeasurement;
    double displayAmount;
    for (int i = 0; i < toMeasurements.Count; i++)
    {
         if (i > 0)
             sb.Append(" ");

          double convertedAmount = VolumeMeasurements(valueToConvert, priorMeasurement, toMeasurement[i]);

          // Check if last item so we don't trim wanted decimals.
          if (i < toMeasurements.Count - 1)
              displayAmount = Math.Floor(convertedAmount)
          else
              displayAmount = convertedAmount;

          valueToConvert = convertedAmount - displayAmount;
          priorMeasurement = toMeasurements[i];

          // You will need to add logic here to display fractions if needed.
          sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1}", displayAmount, toMeasurements[i]);

          if (fixedAmount == 0)
              break;
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Keep in mind that none of this is tested and I really hope this is what you were asking for. This should get you on the right track. You will need to find a way to convert the decimals on the last conversion to display as fractions and implement that. This will at least get you "1 gallon 1.5 cups"

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll work on editing the code and tell you how it goes, I realized I didn't really ask the question but yes you are right in assuming I wanted a function to make 17 1/2 cups to 1 gallon and 1 1/2 cups, and I do already have a fraction function I just have it separate because I just started on the measurement thing so figure it'd be something to work on and just keep adding to it. I usually do something counting through lines but I was actually experimenting with 'switch' statements, and they seemed to do the job just fine so I didn't really need a more compact code.

Comment: That last part there on the switch statements was more in reply to alexie up there, I know they're huge switch statements, but I felt like learning all the parts of c# not just the most compact or quick way.